# Android center_vertical gravity not works

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I am trying to make those `tvGoldName` and `tvGoldValue` to be height of ImageView from the left and be centered vertically. How to achieve that?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llGold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/llToNextLevel"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="right">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivGoldIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/coins"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGoldName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivGoldIcon"

            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/gold"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGoldValue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make both have the same height as the ImageView:

As the `tvGoldName` is in `RelativeLayout` then align its top & bottom the the `ImageView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvGoldName"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivGoldIcon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ivGoldIcon"
```

As the `tvGoldValue` is in the parent `LinearLayout` then:

make its height as match_parent, and align it vertically with `center_vertical` gravity:

```
<TextView
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

But in general, you should be using `ConstraintLayout` to have a flat design without nesting views; and as the `RelativeLayout` has performance issues.

Comment: Seems good. I'll test it out tomorrow. If it works well then I will accept your answer :)